# \includefrom with \includeonly

Tags: include, import

I need `\includefrom` of the `import` package to resolve `input` statements in `chapters/intro/intro.tex`. But when I combine this with `\includeonly`, it is not included:

```
\includeonly{chapters/intro/intro}
\includefrom{chapters/intro/}{intro} % does not get included
```

How can I combine `\includefrom` and `\includeonly`?

I use `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)` and `import.sty` Ver 5.1.

Comment: Can you provide full `MWE`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the file extension is needed in the path. Here is an example:

```
\includeonly{chapters/intro/intro.tex}
\includefrom{chapters/intro}{intro.tex}
```